# async function is not continuing to next line

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm attempting to setup an `async` function so that my next step will not start until the function finishes.

I coded one module to connect to mongodb server, and then check to see if it's connected. These two functions work well together.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoServer = `mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database`;
const consoleColor = { green: '\x1b[42m%s\x1b[0m', yellow: '\x1b[43m%s\x1b[0m', red: '\x1b[41m%s\x1b[0m' }

exports.connectMongoose = () => {
    mongoose.connect(mongoServer, { useNewUrlParser: true });
}

exports.checkState = () => {
    const mongooseState = mongoose.STATES[mongoose.connection.readyState];
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (mongooseState === 'connected') {
            console.log(consoleColor.green, `Mongoose is ${mongooseState}.`);
            resolve();
        } else if (mongooseState === 'connecting') {
            console.log(`Mongoose is ${mongooseState}.`);
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.checkState();
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            console.log(consoleColor.red, `Mongoose is ${mongooseState}.`);
        }
    });
}
```

The next thing I tried to do was connect to the mongo db using my connectMongoose function, and then call a second function that will run my checkState function, and only perform the next function if it resolves (the if statement for the "connected" state.

```
const dbconfig = require('./dbconfig')


dbconfig.connectMongoose()

const testAwait = async () => {
    await dbconfig.checkState();
    console.log("Do this next");
    }
testAwait()
```

The `testAwait` function runs, but it does not get to the `console.log` function which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong when passing the resolve.

Comment: looks like you need to poll `mongooseState` in a Promise, not before it

Comment: @gog do you mean I should move const mongooseState inside the promise? I tried that, didn't make a difference.

Comment: General tip, never poll in a promise and just wait for it. Always race Promises like that against a timeout Promise unless you really don't care if they never ever resolve. `await Promise.race([dbconfig.checkState(), new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 30000, new Error('timed out'))]);` for e.g. a 30 sec timeout.

Comment: @Dynacel code formatting was a bit off and confused me a little. I removed my comment. Additionally I editted your post to be problem-specific rather than any extra information you had about *why* you are learning this and what's your *goals* once you learn this. Rather keep it: 1. code 2. expected behavior 3. unexpected error. :)

Comment: Among the console statements inside the promise, are you seeing any of the inside console statements getting printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.checkState();
}, 1000);
```

When this block is hit, the promise is never resolved. The original promise needs to resolve (as your code is currently, if the status is connecting, a new promise is created, but nothing waits for it, and the original promise never resolves). You could go with a pattern like this:

```js
let attempts = 0;

const isConnected = async () => {
  console.log("checking connection state...");
  attempts++;
  if (attempts >= 5) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const checkState = async () => {
  while (!(await isConnected())) {
    await wait(1000);
  }
  
  return;
};

checkState().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

But to keep it more in line with what you've written, you could do:

```js
const checkState = () => {
    const mongooseState = Math.random() > 0.2 ? "connecting" : "connected";
    
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (mongooseState === 'connected') {
            console.log(`Mongoose is ${mongooseState}.`);
            resolve();
        } else if (mongooseState === 'connecting') {
            console.log(`Mongoose is ${mongooseState}.`);
            setTimeout(() => {
                checkState().then(resolve);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
} 

checkState().then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. I implemented your second solution and it works perfectly. (All I had to do was add .then(resolve).

I had tried that in other ways but none of it helped.

Your first option is actually where I'm headed with the things I WANT to do, so thank you for that as well!

Comment: @Dynacel great, glad that helped. You were really close, and you're trying something (recursive promises) where it's really easy to make slight mistakes.  If you're happy with this answer feel free to accept it

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here in the above code, you are only resolving your promise once. There is no rejection either. Thus, your code is blocked inside the promise. See the below example. You should exit the promise in any case `resolve` or `reject`.

```js
const random = parseInt(Math.random());
const testAwait =
  async() => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (random === 0) {
        resolve(random);
      } else {
        reject(random);
      }
    });
    console.log("Do this next");
  }
testAwait()
```